# ABCPDF Unable to access URL COM error 800c0019 in FACILITY_INTERNET

Tags: c#, .net, abcpdf

I use ABCPDF v8.1.1.1 on win7 x32 with .net 4.0.
When I tried to print page from URl on https I got an error:

> "Unable to render HTML. Unable to access URL COM error 800c0019 in
>   FACILITY_INTERNET. The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on
>   the disk. URL "

```
at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
   at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
```

But when I print on http everything is OK. 
Who know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I think that's the wrong error message. 0x800c0019 = ERROR_SEEK, but it's also INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE. Can you access that site normally - do you see any certificate errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a guess from what Rup said about it being a https issue, it could be that the server cant see the page.

Remember that if this is in production e..g on a live server, its the server that is trying to view the page to add it to the pdf chain, get the URL you are trying to view and load it on the servers broswer.

If might be that if the server is behind a NAT it cant see its own public IP address in which case you need to add a custom entry to the hosts file on the server.

file location = C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Entry should look something like...

```
# Added to resolve websites locally, instead of to their public IPs
127.0.0.1   www.yourdomain.com
```